# NSFetchedResultsController does not read updated derived value in CoreData entity after RestKit EntityMapping update

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, restkit

I have a view controller where I create an NSFetchedResultsController to display a set of CoreData objects in a TableView.  While viewing these objects in the tableview, they are updated by calling a RestKit getObjectsAtPath, which processes correctly through a response descriptor and RKEntityMapping to update a field on the CoreData objects.  However, this particular entity also have a custom derived field - actually a state machine (TransitionKit based) that reads the state value provided to the entity and re-initializes the state machine with the state provided by the server.  However, no matter where I reinitialize the state machine (awakeFromFetch, willSave, key-value observing), this reinitialized state machine is not updated when the copy of the object in the NSFetchedResultsController is used to update the corresponding table cell (when the NSFetchResultsController is notified of the change on that row).  To be clear - the value that is updated via the RestKit EntityMapping IS updated, but the state machine (a derived value) is not updated.   WHY would this be?

Shouldn't the NSFetchedResultsController's array of objects be notified in a way that allows them to compute their derived values?  When I trace in the code, awakeFromFetch in the main thread does not yet contain the updated value, and computing my derived value in willSave or a setter does not seem to create this derived value in the instance of the object that is held by the NSFetchedResultsController.

I've attached my base model code

```
#import "VCStateMachineManagedObject.h"

@interface VCStateMachineManagedObject ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) TKStateMachine * stateMachine;

@end



@implementation VCStateMachineManagedObject

@dynamic savedState;
@synthesize stateMachine = _stateMachine;
@synthesize forcedState;

-(id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if(self != nil) {
    }
    return self;
}


- (BOOL)canFireEvent:(id)eventOrEventName {
    return [_stateMachine canFireEvent:eventOrEventName];
}

- (BOOL)fireEvent:(id)eventOrEventName userInfo:(NSDictionary *)userInfo error:(NSError **)error{
   return [_stateMachine fireEvent:eventOrEventName userInfo:userInfo error:error];
}

- (void) assignStatesAndEvents:(TKStateMachine *) stateMachine {
    [NSException raise:@"Invoked abstract method" format:@"Invoked abstract method"];
}

- (NSString *) getInitialState {
    [NSException raise:@"Invoked abstract method" format:@"Invoked abstract method"];
    return nil;
}


- (void)awakeFromInsert {
    if(self.savedState == nil){
        self.savedState = [self getInitialState];
    }
    [self createStateMachine];
}

- (void)awakeFromFetch {
    if(self.savedState == nil){
        self.savedState = [self getInitialState];
    }
    [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"savedState" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
    [self createStateMachine];
}


- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if(![[_stateMachine.currentState name] isEqualToString:self.savedState]){
        [self createStateMachine];
    }
}

- (void) willSave {
    NSLog(@"%@", self.savedState);
    [self createStateMachine];
}


// Manually set the state, for restkit object mapping
- (void) setForcedState: (NSString*) state__ {
    self.savedState = state__;
}

- (void) setSavedState:(NSString *)savedState__{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"savedState"];
    [self setPrimitiveValue:savedState__ forKey:@"savedState"];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"savedState"];
    [self createStateMachine];
}

- (NSString *) state {
    NSString * state = [_stateMachine.currentState name];
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", state, self.savedState];
}


#pragma mark - State Machine

- (void)prepareStateMachine {
    for(TKEvent * event in _stateMachine.events){
        [event setDidFireEventBlock:^(TKEvent *event, TKTransition *transition) {
            self.savedState = transition.destinationState.name;
        }];
    }
}

- (void) createStateMachine {
    _stateMachine = [TKStateMachine new];
    [self assignStatesAndEvents:_stateMachine];
    [self prepareStateMachine];
    _stateMachine.initialState = [_stateMachine stateNamed:self.savedState];
    [_stateMachine activate];
}


@end
```

@quellish
Here's what I see when I trace breakpoints in my managed object.

1. I call out to restkit to download new objects
2. Restkit downloads objects in a background thread (not the main thread). I see it find the matching object (awakeFromFetch), update the state (setForcedState), and save (willSave), and on this instance of the object I see the createStateMachine method called several times (which is because I have it in all these functions, though that of course has no effect on the instance in the NSFetchedResultsController).
3. I then see an object on the main thread get fetched (awakeFromFetch) and go through the same process.
4. I then see an object on the main thread get triggered by KVO and again go through the createStateMachine method.

in all causes when I view variables in the state machine, they have been updated to the correct value.  but THEN, when NSFetchedResultsController triggers on the change, the state machine IS NOT updated even though the value itself is.

In the next few hours I'm going to trace back through this and give even more specific information about the behavior I'm seeing.  I'm also going to add a UUID to each instance of the entity to make sure that the one that is being updated is actually the one that's in the NSFetchedResultsController.  Stay tuned.

Comment: Is KVO fired for the key? Is it 'just' a timing issue (so the FRC is updated before the KVO notification hits the MO itself)?

Comment: That's one of the weird things that I can't figure out.  YES, KVO is fired for the key, I can trace it through my observeValueForKeyPath: method, and it would seem all would be well.  But in the view controller when the object is read, the state machine nevertheless does not have the updated value (though savedState does).

Comment: Why did you choose to use `setPrimitiveValue:forKey:` ? It looks like your implementation may be breaking CoreData's faulting and key value observation.

Comment: I switched it to setPrimitive because doing it the normal way wasn't working.  Changing it back has no effect on the behavior, and as I mentioned KVO and awakeFromFetch appear to be called on the main thread.

Comment: They're being called on the main thread when you're using a private context with performBlock, or performBlockAndWait? performBlockAndWait will almost always execute from the calling thread, but should not be used for anything that modifies the faulting state of a managed object.

Comment: This is where it gets complex.  I'm going to post what I see when I trace in the question, please read it an give me your impression, you might know something I don't.

Comment: "when NSFetchedResultsController triggers on the change" what do you mean when you say that? Can you elaborate?

Comment: NSFetchedResultsController is reading from this collection of entities.  When RestKit finishes updating, NSFetchedResultsController gets triggered and repopulates the tableview.

Comment: Well, not exactly. RestKit saves an NSManagedObjectContext. The NSFetchedResultsController is listening for managed object context change notifications, and matches the objects in the notification against the managed object IDs it previously fetched, etc. Is it listening on the same context? If these are two different contexts, are they parent-child (I should hope so!) or are they using merge notifications?

Comment: Yeah I do understand that much.  I'm using RestKit out of the box, which means that I only have so much control or understanding of it's internals.  What I do know is that I set it up with the same managed object context that I use throughout my app.  I originally used mainQueueManagedObjectContext, and have in other apps without issue, but also tried persistentStoreManagedObjectContext as I was learning and attempting my debug of this problem.  What I have seen is that restkit accesses the context on a separate thread from the UI.

Comment: And yes, the NSFetchedResultsController is created with the same context as restkit objectmanager is assigned.  I do not create any additional managed object contexts in this application at this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implemention you provided in your question has a few issues. Your accessor and KVO observation implementations are working against you and seem to be interfering with Core Data's change tracking, which is KVO based.

Here are some of the things you can improve that may fix the issue you're seeing. This will definitely help some issues you may not have run into yet, but most certainly will.

`observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:`
A correct implementation should check the context pointer against the known value you passed to `addObserver:forKeyPath:context:` and `removeObserver:forKeyPath:context:`. This allows you to differentiate your observations from others. Which leads to the next point-
A correct implementation calls super. If the context value is NOT your known value, defer to super. Example:

Adding the observer:

```
[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:keyPath options:options context:(__bridge void*)self];
```

Removing the observer:

```
[self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:keyPath context:(__bridge void*)self];
```

`observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:` implementation:

```
- (void) observeValueForKeyPath: (NSString *) keyPath ofObject: (id) object change: (NSDictionary *) change context: (void *) context {
    if ((__bridge id)context == self){
        // This is our observation, handle it here.
                [self setStateMachine:nil];
    } else {
        // This is important for Core Data to work correctly. 
        [super observeValueForKeyPath: keyPath ofObject: object change: change context: context];
    }
}
```

CoreData uses KVO extensively to track changes to managed object snapshots. When using KVO with Core Data you should be aware of this, and be careful not to implement KVO correctly for Core Data - which is slightly different than for other objects. For example, automatic KVO notifications are OFF by default for modeled properties of NSManagedObject subclasses.
This means that if a property is backed by a modeled attribute, it will not, by default, emit external KVO notifications. Properties that do not exist in the model *will*.

To enable automatic KVO notifications for a modeled property, implement a class method using the following pattern:

```
+ (BOOL) automaticallyNotifiesObserversFor<PropertyName> {
    return YES;
}
```

Where  is the name of the modeled property (i.e. `automaticallyNotifiesObserversForSavedState`).

In your case you have chosen to implement custom accessors for your modeled property. It's not clear why you chose to do this from the code you posted (perhaps your saw the scary warning in the `willSave:` documentation about recursion - your will/didChangeValueForKey messages reintroduce this). It's *very rare* that it is necessary to provide your own accessor implementation for a managed object subclass. Normally Core Data provides an accessor for @dynamic properties at runtime. When it does so, it provides an implementation that has correct memory management and change tracking, as well as optimizations for CPU and memory.

Primitive accessor methods are for accessing the *attributes* of a managed object. This essentially means an instance variable backed directly by the value from the data model. Accessing attributes as primitive values is not recommended, and very rarely worthwhile. Always prefer the property accessors to get correct behavior from Core Data and your model objects.

- Fix your KVO implementation using the guidance above.
- Don't override `init` on managed object subclasses. `init` isn't the designated initialzier.
- Move from implementing your own accessor for your modeled property to allowing Core Data to provide the implementation. This should be as simple as removing your current accessor implementation.
- If you change your NSKeyValueObservationOptions to include NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial, you will get a KVO notification for the initial value of the observed key path. In your case, this would be an opportunity to also set an intial state for your state machine.
- Since you're implementing some kind of state machine, it is probably a good idea to allow KVO to manage your dependancies between values (i.e. between forcedState, savedState, and stateMachine). For example, set savedState as a dependant keypath of forcedState, so that when savedState changes the system knows that forcedState should be "dirty" and needs recalculation:

  ```
  + (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForForcedState {
  return [NSSet setWithObject:@"savedState"];
  ```

  }
- Updating your state machine from the managed object life cycle methods will probably not be necessary once your KVO implementation is fixed. If you do decide to stick with life cycle methods, see if awakeFromSnapshotEvents: is more suited to your needs.

Since you don't seem to be *mutating* your state machine much at all, just recreating it, your use case is pretty simple. If I am reading your class correctly, all you need to do is set `stateMachine` to nil when KVO tells you that `savedState` has changed. If it is nil when `state` is accessed, call your create method to set the property. Most transient properties are implemented this way.

Comment: Thanks, I will step through these recommendations and update on what happens.  I'll also update with a class that is less of a 'debug' scenario and more of the real use case.